# Is there any way to only allow a user to enter in a page with mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, amazon-s3

Is there any way to only allow a user to enter in a web page with mobile browser? For example, to block a user that tries to access a web page with a desktop browser. I’m using aws to host my web page, nodejs and vuejs

Comment: Assume there is, have a go, and then come back with a [mcve] if you run into any issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using vue

`npm i -S vue-mobile-detection`

then

```
 <div v-if="$isMobile()">MOBILE</div>
 <div v-else>DESKTOP OR TABLET</div>
```

https://renatello.com/vue-js-detect-mobile/

---

Another way

```
function _isMobile(){
    // if we want a more complete list use this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
    // str.test() is more efficent than str.match()
    // remember str.test is case sensitive
    var isMobile = (/iphone|ipod|android|ie|blackberry|fennec/).test
         (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    return isMobile;
}

if(!isMobile()){
//redirect to google or do something else
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```